# Using AWS Codecommit in an organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

We are planning to use AWS codecommit in our organisation. 
Our scenario is,we have a IAM user named "codeAdmin", who can create repositories. 
My question is how to handle the developers in the AWS codecommit. We have the following scenarios in consideration

1. for every developer create a new IAM account (added under the required group) and then provide access to the required codecommit repositories.
   This way,if we have 30 developers,we need to create 30 IAM users.
2. or to give each developer the acccessKey and accessId of a single IAM developer account. 
   In this way,if we have 30 developers, we need to create only 1 IAM user and share the accessKeys/Ids to all.

Which approach from the above is best suited? Or is there any other best practices to be followed?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create separate iam user for each user is better.

First, different users may have different permissions based on their experience and position. For example, maybe you only want admin user have the ability to delete the repository.
Second, using different users can help your team distinguish which developers create a pull request, which developers comments on the pull request. If 30 developers share the same iam user, you won't know who make the comments, create pull request, merge the pull request because they are always the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's best practice is to create separate account for each user. There are many benefits to this starting from permissions based on user's experience/position to (most probably the most important) traceability. If you only have 1 account and somebody messes things up (hopefully won't happen) you have no idea who it was and what was the mistaken driven by.

You can read up a bit on this :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html

Best regards!